# password_verify is consistently returning false

Tags: php, authentication

I'm having an issue getting `password_verify` to validate the password.

I have the password stored in the database using

```php
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
```

On the login page, I have the user enter their username and password and retrieve the input via the post method `$_POST['pwd']` (which is the user's input for the password).

I then retrieve the hashed password from the database and check it against the password from the login

```php
if(password_verify($password, $results['password']))
```

I can't seem to figure out why the password never seems to match. I've read filter/escape can affect `password_verify()` and changed that as well and got the same result. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <?PHP 
     include('connection.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $password = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pwd', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $results = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $savedHash =  $results['password'];

    //echo $savedHash;

    if(password_verify($password, $savedhash)){
    echo "yes " . $password;
    }else{
    echo "no";
    }         
    ?>
```

Comment: Other than using `trim()`, I wouldn't perform any filtering or transformation of any kind on the posted `pwd` value

Comment: @mario in the interest of keeping OP's blood pressure down, could you explain how that's a relevant duplicate?

Comment: @Phil Because of the notice. (Variable names / case-sensitivity)

Comment: @mario ah, nicely spotted. To point out the obvious, `$savedHash` is not the same as `$savedhash`

Comment: even with that typo fixed the problem is still the same. That was a mistake I made from trying to figure out the problem. @phil

Comment: @Silverback please make sure you [follow the instructions above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) to get better error reporting enabled. Then, please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61491757/edit) to match your current code. If you can do all that and are still having issues, we can try and get your question re-opened